# Staging repos and dependent artifacts

Tags: maven, maven-3, release, staging, sonatype

I'm using sonatype nexus repo hosting and I have two artifacts where A depends on B but they are separate projects (not multimodule). I staged B as 1.0.0 but now I want to stage A with a dependency on B-1.0.0 and not on its snapshot; however, because B is still just staged and not released, maven complains that it can't find B-1.0.0. What is the correct way to do this? It doesn't make sense to me to have to release the dependency (B) without it being tested as part of another project (A)

What am I doing wrong? IIUC, staging repos are dynamically created, so adding the (temporary) staging repo as a `<repository>` in project A doesn't sound good either

as a secondary question, I also would like to know if I am supposed to stage the main artifact (A) in the same staging repo as B or if I should close B and stage A in a new staging repo

Comment: Based on what you are writing it sound they should be part of a multi-module build instead. But you can configure in Nexus a staged repository to be used during the usual solution for dependencies whic h would solve the problem before you close the staged repository.

Comment: one of them (B) is a generic library not really constrained to its current lone user, so i don't want to keep them in the same git repo/maven project

Answer (score 0):

You should have a separate repository group from public and have it configured as the target group for your staging profile for project A.

Then when you build project B you use that group and it will be available for building that project.